# SHOW CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost'; gives me ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Why is this wrong syntax? This is the exact command used in the example in the documentation for both MySQL and MariaDB.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'USER 'root'@'localhost'' at line 1
```

Comment: MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
+--------------------------------------------+
| @@SESSION.sql_mode                         |
+--------------------------------------------+
| NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+--------------------------------------------+

Answer (score 0):

The reason the command is not working is that my version of MariaDB is 10.1.47-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 when it should be >= 10.2.0 according to [the MariaDB Knowledge Base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-create-user/)